# Can two wizards read the same spell from one scroll at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I was asked this question from one of my group and I am wondering if two wizards
 can read the same spell say fireball from the same scroll at the same time and in effect have two fireballs created?

Answer (score 13):

### Yes...

Two wizards *can* recite a scroll together. Mechanically, this is done by one of them using the Help action, followed by the other using the Use an Object action.

### ...but No.

This does not cast *Fireball* twice.  It grants advantage on the DC 13 Intelligence check required to use the scroll if the (second) wizard is below 5th level.

Comment: A pair of low-level wizards struggling to harness power beyond their ken, chanting "The power of phlogiston compels you!" would be pretty cool, too.

Comment: I never considered Helping to read a scroll before. Definitely a good idea there.

Answer (score 12):

No.

You can think of the scroll as a battery: A scroll contains the stored energy of a single spell. Thus, casting/releasing a spell from a scroll can only result in the same amount of magical energy as the scroll was loaded up with when written.

Answer (score 5):

No.  The scroll is consumed as it's cast so there's no effective way to share it.